# What is the difference between "||" and "or" in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the difference between "||" and "or"?

I tried doing this in PHP:

```
$a = false || true;
$b = false or true;

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

You obviously think that the result would be `true` for `$a` and `true` for `$b`, but the result I got is this:

```
boolean true
boolean false
```

Comment: In a nutshell, `||` has precedence over `OR`. Yet, they both basically do the same thing.

Comment: This is very clearly stated in the manual. See [PHP: Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"||" has a greater precedence than "or".

An example (from the PHP documentation):

```
<?php
    // "||" has a greater precedence than "or"
    $e = false || true; // $e will be assigned to (false || true) which is true
    $f = false or true; // $f will be assigned to false
    var_dump($e, $f);
?>
```

Read more here: *[Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)*

Comment: I'd suggest to use braces though, in cases like:

- true || 1 OR 0 
- true || (1 || 0)
`